# Not able to select edges

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges

[image]

I'm not able to select the edges or vertices on one of my models. Anyone have a clue as to why? I can select everything else around it fine (faces, vertices, edges), but not the ones in between the ones i've highlighted in the image attached..

Comment: There have been a bug in some 2.9 versions, maybe try Alt H, if it still doesn't work, please share your object: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It looks like there is a (solidify?) modifier at work that pushes generated geometry over the outer surface. You cannot select or edit generated geometry. Let´s say it´s not real at this moment. Apply the modifier or adjust the settings.

Comment: Looks like an un-applied subsurface modifier to me, and the generated geometry is inside the editable mesh. I think relaxed is right, just apply the modifier.